# simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php won't be overridden

Tags: 6, theming, emails

My newsletter is almost ready, where it not that the node title ends up in the sent testmail as well. So I figured if I would just override the `simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php`
I followed the guidelines from [this](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!simplenews!theme!simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php/6) page.

In my simplenews configuration I just checked just the generic content type that simplenews generated. In that same configuration page, I chose 'newsletter' as the taxonomy term attached to it. This makes the filename `simplenews-newsletter-body--newsletter.tpl.php`

The idea to just delete the following line from the copied file: 
`<h2><?php print $title ?></h2>`

The tutorial I mentioned says to paste in into the custom theme folder directly. I was assuming not in the templates folder. I tried both though while flushing cashes at least twice after each try. Still getting the darn title in my test mail.

UPDATE: I discovered that the filename needs to be the term ID of the simplenews newsletter, being a number. I looked up the `tid` and changed the `tpl` filename accordingly - in my case making it `simplenews-newsletter-body--110.tpl.php`. Of course the needed flushing of cashes. Didn't help either.

Comment: When you changed it to be the tid vs the node type, did you put it in your theme's templates folder?  That's where this should live, and I just wanted to make sure you did leave it in that location...

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I tried both places. The tutorial says to put it in the theme folder, while common sense and yourself says it should be theme's template folder. Tried both places again. Nothing.

Comment: Yes, I did see that, I just couldn't tell if you had tried it after renaming.  Actually it shouldn't matter anyway.  Hmm, I'll see if I can think of something else..

Answer (score 1):

The file may need to go in the admin theme folder, if you're using admin theme/sections, and not in the regular theme folder. Worth a shot.